# Get index element which has a specific initial in listview

Tags: javascript, android, listview, substring

I have a problem with listview.

I'm filling the list with an array, this list is completely custom, and I want that if an element of this array begins with "-R", then that cell must be different from the others (color, font, etc.).

the problem is that I can not take the index of the cell that begins with "-R".

this is the code:

```
arrayEserCardio = "try;find;-Reply;Again;"

var indexEserSplit = arrayEserCardio.toString().split(";");

for (var i =0; i<indexEserSplit.length;i++) {

 var eserSingle = indexEserSplit[i];

var link_markup ='<li id="listCardio2"><a onclick="rowSelectedEserCardio()" href="#" class="ui-link-inherit"><div class="textScheda"><p style="white-space: normal" class="titleEs">'+eserSingle+'</p></div></a></li>';   

if(eserSingle.substring(0,2)=='-R') {
var initial = eserSingle.substring(0,2);

   var index = arrayEserCardio.indexOf(initial);

  //but index return wrong
}

}
```

I hope I was clear, I do not know javascript very well.. thanks to all

Comment: One the main problems is in the first line. You can't have an array where the elements are separated by semicolons.

Comment: Why not? the list is filled well ...

Comment: Please. First fix the arrayEserCardio. if you want the reste of the code to work and want to split on `;` try this `arrayEserCardio = "try;find;-Reply;Again";

Comment: @Ilario not it's a syntax error. Juste try it in a console. you will get : `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list`

Comment: @llario, because if you look at your console you'll see it generates a javascript syntax error.

Comment: sorry I was wrong to write the array, it is now right

Comment: Where does the `for...loop` finish? After the `if statement` or before? You're missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: why do you need the index? using indexOf will give you only the first matched index so every time the same one (as we enter in this section only when initial equal to "-R". At least use indexOf(eserSingle) but if you ave -Reply and -Replys you will get the same problem. whe not using `i` for index?

Comment: @peernohell I need the index of '-R' in order to change that cell, I'm wrong? I'd know you recommend another way?

Comment: What do you need to change that cell to?

Comment: @Andy in the particular cell I need to edit: the height of the cell, the background color and font

Comment: By _cell_, are you talking about the list item, the one on the line that starts `var link_markup`? If that's the case, add a class to it and use CSS to change the style.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your time, it is as you say, but I can not figure out how to change the particular cell ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
var
arrayEserCardio = "try;find;-Reply;Again;",
var indexEserSplit = arrayEserCardio.split(";"),
eserSingle,
link_markup,
i;

for (var i = 0; i < indexEserSplit.length; i++) {

    eserSingle = indexEserSplit[i];
    cls = "titleEs";
    if (eserSingle.substring(0,2) == '-R') {
        cls += " with_min_r";
    }
    link_markup ='<li id="listCardio2"><a onclick="rowSelectedEserCardio()" href="#" class="ui-link-inherit"><div class="textScheda"><p style="white-space: normal" class="' + cls + '">' + eserSingle + '</p></div></a></li>';   

}
```

Comment: I made a quick edit to prevent duplicate ids on your list items, otherwise this is the solution I came up with.

Answer (score -1):

It should have been

```
if (eserSingle.substring(0, 2).equals("-R")) {

}
```

The == operator compares the object references, not the value of the Strings.

Comment: no. == work perfectly this statement `"-Ready".substring(0,2) == '-R'` return true.

Comment: testing onf Safari: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'eserSingle.substring(0,2).equals("-R")')